# Can't see partition after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have just installed Ubuntu on my computer on a new partition but after the installation, I can't find my D (Media) partition on Windows 7 although it is shown as NTFS in GParted.

Here are the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you run chkdsk from Windows on it? But Windows may not even let you run chkdsk as it does not seem to see it as NTFS. Is Windows saying it is RAW?  Gparted is looking at partition table which says NTFS, but Windows also looks at partition boot sector which must have Windows boot code if bootable and exact same start & size info of partition as partition table. If partition boot sector incorrect Windows may not see it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix This may restore backup partition boot sector if valid.

Comment: Windows doesn't see that partition correctly either. From Windows, you might try assigning a drive letter, like "D:" to that partition, and then run `chkdsk /f d:`.

Comment: I can still access it on Ubuntu and I've transfered all of it onto E:
I don't know why E: and D: are the same on Gparted yet windows can only see E:

Comment: If Ubuntu can access the partition but Windows can't it's a Windows problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do as user heynnema said. to assign a drive letter, right click the partition, and click "change drive letter and paths". next click "add" on the popup window, and choose a letter to assign (i.e. D).

Comment: Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu ;-)**.  What you're giving is a *Windows* answer which is off-topic here...

Comment: whoops - i saw the windows disk management and forgot!

Comment: please delete my comments/answer if you want!

Comment: We're not like that.  If you agree, delete.  If you disagree...  It'll be deleted automatically in a year's time anyway.  **;-)**